# I don't know where's the error. C/C++

Tags: struct, strtok, strcpy

Hello everyone I have this code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct ficha{
    char dni[9];
    char nombre[20];
    char p_apellido[20];
    char s_apellido[20];
    char telefono[9];
};



 ficha fichas[20]; //creamos array de tipo ficha de 20
 ficha aux[20]; //creamos array auxiliar para almacenar datos

 int main(){

     FILE *fp; //creamos variable tipo file que se llama fp
     fp=fopen("datos.txt", "r"); // abrimos en fp el archivo datos.txt con permiso de lectura (r)

     if(fp == NULL){
        perror("Error al abrir el archivo");
        return(-1);
     }
     else{
        char *ptr;
        char *tmp;

         for (int i =0; i<10; i++){//si hay mas de 10 elementos cambiar 10 por el numero que sea.
         fscanf(fp,"%s",aux[i].dni); //almacenando datos de fichero en aux[i]
         }
        for (int i =0; i<10; i++){
            tmp=aux[i].dni;
            ptr = strtok(tmp,"; \n");
            printf("PTR %i:%s \n",i,ptr);
            strcpy(fichas[i].dni, ptr); //almacenando dni en fichas
            printf("ficha %i : \n DNI: %s ",i,fichas[i].dni);
            printf ("DNIBUENO: %s   ", fichas[0].dni);

            ptr = strtok(NULL,"; \n"); //te lo hace hasta NULL
            printf ("DNIBUENO1: %s", fichas[0].dni);
            printf("PTR %i:%s \n",i,ptr);
            printf ("DNIBUENO2: %s", fichas[0].dni);
            strcpy(fichas[i].nombre, ptr); //almacenando nombre
            printf ("DNIBUENO3: %s", fichas[0].dni);
            printf("Nombre: %s ",fichas[i].nombre);
            printf("auxatope %i:%s \n",i,fichas[0].dni);

            ptr = strtok(NULL,"; \n");
            printf("PTR %i:%s \n",i,ptr);
            strcpy(fichas[i].p_apellido, ptr); //apellido
            printf("1 Apellido: %s ",fichas[i].p_apellido);

            ptr = strtok(NULL,"; \n");
            printf("PTR %i:%s \n",i,ptr);

            strcpy(fichas[i].s_apellido, ptr); //2 apellido
            printf("2 Apellido: %s ",fichas[i].s_apellido);

            ptr = strtok(NULL,"; \n");
                    printf("PTR %i:%s \n",i,ptr);
            strcpy(fichas[i].telefono, ptr); //telefono
            printf("Telefono %s \n", fichas[i].telefono);
        }
   }
    fclose(fp);



    return 0;
 }
```

I put a lot of printf to know what is the value variable in each moment.

My problems begins when I try to insert nombre (name) inside my struct array, the fichas[i].dni takes the name too and his value is 34567890DDIEGO when must be 34567890D.

I don't know if it's the strtok or the strcpy. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using for example *snprintf* instead of *strcpy* , it's much easier to avoid buffer overflow with that.